# Force serverless lambda function to use boto3 installed in venv instead of the one already available in AWS Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, boto3, serverless

I am facing issues with boto3(1.9.42) readily comes with AWS which fails when I run certain commands. But same issue is not faced when I run the script locally because boto3 installed locally is 1.9.118 version where as aws comes with 1.9.42.

```
client_api = boto3.client(service_name='apigatewaymanagementapi', endpoint_url=endpoint_url)
[ERROR] UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'apigatewaymanagementapi
```

I know there is no direct way to replace boto3 in aws. Is there any way I can deploy the local boto3 to aws and use the module from aws lambda functions.

Comment: If you package it in the deployment zip file, just like you would package any other library your Lambda function depends on, then it will use that version.

Comment: How do I package boto3 in deployment zip? I am using docker for external dependencies @MarkB

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html